# LocalDateTime isAfter and isBefore config time

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

Issue in finding time falls between startTime and endTime. I have config like

timeframe1 = C1|04:00|11.59 timeframe2 = C2|20.00|03:59 timeframe3 = C3|12.00|19.59      I need to get the currentime and check whether it falls in which timeFrame , right now I am doing like

```
Map<String, String> t1 = new HashMap(){{
        t1.put("cust", "C1");
        t1.put("startTime", "04:00");
        t1.put("endTime", "11.59");
    }}
    Map<String, String> t2 = new HashMap(){{
        t2.put("cust", "C1");
        t2.put("startTime", "20.00");
        t2.put("endTime", "03:59");
    }}
    Map<String, String> t3 = new HashMap(){{
        t3.put("cust", "C1");
        t3.put("startTime", "12.00");
        t3.put("endTime", "19.59");
    }}
    List<Map<String, String> listValues = Arrays.asList(t1,t2,t3); 

    LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());

    Optional<Map<String, Object>> timeFrame = listValues.stream()
        .filter(l -> {
            LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalTime.parse(String.valueOf(l.get("startTime")))).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
            LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalTime.parse(String.valueOf(l.get("endTime")))).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
            return currentTime.isAfter(startTime) && currentTime.isBefore(endTime);
        }).findFirst();

    return timeFrame.get()
```

But the issue is -> if current time is 21:00 then it should return timeframe2 map details

but the condition currentTime.isAfter(startTime) && currentTime.isBefore(endTime) ) fails, as endTime is 03:59 .

Please help on how to find the correct result.

Comment: `21:00` is after `20:00`, but **not** before `03:59`, which makes the result you're getting valid. Remember this is **on the same day**. It would return true for that entry if the end time was on the next day... Please make sure that the code you post does compile and run, it's otherwise hard to get to the problem...

Comment: Don't use "double brace initialisation" - it doesn't do what you think it does. It creates an anonymous class for each of your maps, this causes all sorts of strange and unexpected problems. This is especially true because you're not even taking advantage of its only "benefit".

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski please don't make edits that materially change the code or meaning of the OP. Fixing the code in the OP is not the intent of edits.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry. I thought making the code compile in an edit is fine, but apparently [it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88627/how-far-can-i-refactor-the-code-in-someone-elses-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the job (dirty as it is - you had better refactor it into a separate method):

```
.filter(l -> {
    LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(l.get("startTime"));
    LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse(l.get("endTime"));

    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
    return startTime.isBefore(endTime)
            ? currentTime.isAfter(startTime) && currentTime.isBefore(endTime)
            : currentTime.isAfter(startTime) || currentTime.isBefore(endTime);
})
```

**EDIT**: One important addition here. Your time ranges have holes in them because they are inclusive from both sides. Example: when `currentTime` is 19:59:31, a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown because no time frame includes such time. The same is with 20:00:00.

Therefore, I'd suggest making the `endTime` exclusive and specifying it as full hour (e.g. 20:00). Then you'd also need to change `currentTime.isAfter(startTime)` into `!startTime.isBefore(currentTime)`, like this:

```
    return startTime.isBefore(endTime)
            ? !startTime.isBefore(currentTime) && currentTime.isBefore(endTime)
            : !startTime.isBefore(currentTime) || currentTime.isBefore(endTime);
```

Comment: You'd be better off just adding a day to the end time if it's before the start.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I tried that initially (see the edit), but it's not that simple, because: A) you need to add the day to `endTime` if `currentTime` is after 20:00 *or* B) subtract the day from `startTime` if `currentTime` is before 4:00. To sum up, it gets unnecessarily complex when using full dates instead of times only.

Comment: Not sure I understand you - the current time is a fully resolved UTC timestamp. The start time will be a timestamp today - this never needs to be changed. The only situation where we have a problem is if the end time ends up _before_ the start time - this (according to the OP) means that the end time is actually tomorrow, so add a day. I don't see where 8pm and 4am come into it...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Assume `currentTime` is 3am:today (BTW. I never suggested changing `currentTime`). When you deal with the 8pm-4am timeframe, and you add one day to `endTime`, you end up with 8pm:today-4am:tomorrow. Can you see that 3am:today is not included into such time span?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yet it should be! :) In what other timeframe would you have 3am?

Comment: In a timeframe that starts _before_ 3am today!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174321/discussion-between-tomasz-linkowski-and-boris-the-spider).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski, thanks for the answer, currently I added this condition  if(startTime.isAfter(endTime)) return currentTime.isAfter(startTime) || currentTime.isBefore(endTime);

This is fine right ? and also changed time to 04:00 - 12:00, 12:00 - 20:00. 20:00 - 04:00

The solution is working, why I need to change the condition to !startTime.isBefore(currentTime) ??

Comment: Try it out with `LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.of(20, 0)`. In other words, when the time is exactly 20:00, the code throws an exception - that's why you need `!startTime.isBefore(currentTime)`. PS. Please use backticks (`) for code in comments.